# Master to Slave to Slave Configuration in MySQL

Tags: mysql, replication

We currently have 3 MySQL Servers running;

- the first which contains production data and is due to be retired

  mysqld  Ver 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

  mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS;
  Empty set (0.00 sec)
- the second which contains out of date snapshot of production data and is to take over from the first.

  mysqld  Ver 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3-log for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

  [Master Status](http://pastebin.com/JTL3i2gf)
- the third which is already a slave of the second server.

  mysqld  Ver 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

  mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS;
  Empty set (0.01 sec)

My question is would I go about setting up the following?:

First Server (master) -> Second Server (slave) -> Third Server (slave)

Tutorial links welcome! I tried to Google, but I'm sure I've gotten the wrong keywords

Comment: 1) How much data are we talking ? 2) How much downtime are you willing to accept? 3) Are all three DB servers running the same version of MySQL ?

Comment: 50MB, server 1 can't go down for more than a minute, server 2/3 are expendable for now, No.

Comment: OK you said 50MB. Do you have binary logging enabled on the first server ???

Comment: doesn't appear to have it running

Comment: Please run `SHOW MASTER STATUS;` on all three DB Servers and tell me what you see.

Comment: I have recently updated the snapshot on server 2 by request of the boss

Comment: I am sorry. Rather than grill you with questions on details, here is a post I made back on Aug 12, 2012 on how to setup Replication step-by-step : http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/23316/877

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7339/discussion-between-jharwood-and-rolandomysqldba)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [**our chat conversation**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7339/discussion-between-jharwood-and-rolandomysqldba), here is what was discussed

- Server1 is Stand Alone
- Server2 is a Master
- Server3 is a Slave to Server2

This implies that binary logging is enabled in Server2.

To Make Server1 a Master of Server2, perform the following:

**STEP 01** : On Server2, add this to `/etc/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
log-slave-updates
```

**STEP 02** : On Server3, run `STOP SLAVE;`

**STEP 03** : On Server2, run `service mysql restart`

**STEP 04** : On Server3, run `START SLAVE;`

**STEP 06** : On Server1, add this to `/etc/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
log-bin=mysql-bin
```

**STEP 07** : On Server1, run `service mysql restart`

**STEP 08** : Set Replication From Server1 to Server2

See [Clarification about master slave configuration in mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23297/clarification-about-master-slave-configuration-in-mysql/23316#23316)

## OPTIONAL

Once you have MySQL Replication Going From Server1 to Server2 to Server3, your can properly load all data into all three MySQL Instances by doing the following on Server1:

```
mysqldump -u... -p... --all-databases --routines --triggers > mysqldata.sql
mysql -u... -p... < mysqldata.sql
```

This will do three(3) things

- Repopulate everything into Server1
- MySQL Replication will handle populating Server2 from Server1
- MySQL Replication will handle populating Server3 from Server2

Since your data is 50MB in total, this should be execute very quickly.